# jcifs.smb.SmbException: A duplicate name exists on the network

Tags: spring, security, ntlm, jcifs

I am getting below Exception while using Spring Security NTLM (2.0.4).

We are using Domain Controller.

This Domain controller is designed to resolve multiple IP address in order to provide load balancing.

Is there any way to handle this using Spring NTLM.

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: A duplicate name exists on the network.
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:522)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:622)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:280)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:233)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:154)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.logon(SmbSession.java:169)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.logon(SmbSession.java:162)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ntlm.NtlmProcessingFilter.logon(NtlmProcessingFilter.java:410)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ntlm.NtlmProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(NtlmProcessingFilter.java:339)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
```

While searching for solution, we came across some suggestions that we need to modify NTLMProcessingFilter class.

JAR: spring-security-ntlm-2.0.4.jar.
Class: NtlmProcessingFilter.java
Method: getDCAddress()
Code changes:
Existing:      dc = UniAddress. getByName (domainController, true);

Modified : UniAddress dc = UniAddress.getByName( domainController, true );
              dc = UniAddress.getByName( dc.getHostAddress(), true );

But we dont have choice to modify the JAR code.
can anyone please suggest the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Srini

Comment: Why not? Copy code, create your own filter, apply modification and use your custom filter instead of the default Spring Security one.

Comment: Hi M.Deinum, Thanks for your reply..but our client is not happy with the jar changes. And one more thing..we will create one new class  for filter and remaining dependencies can we keep same is it?

Comment: You are using a piece of software that has been deprecated 6 years ago, so what would you expect? In theory everything else can be kept the same.